# bootstrap columns for iphone and ipad are the same, how to get another size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been developing a bootstrap website and I have found 1 very major flaw, it treats tablet size the same as phone size, the col-xs-x (for 768px and under)  applies to iphone and ipad alike.

http://www.think.darkstarmedia.net/

With my design I use 2 columns for desktop and tablet size, once in the phone size I want it to be 1 column but bootstrap has no way to do that

I know I could create 2 copies of the exact same content and use media queries (e.g. display:none, display:block) and swap them out for under 480 pixels, but that seems like it goes against the whole point of using something like bootstrap..

Is there anyway  to use bootstrap's columns to accomplish what I want..

e.g.
col-sm-3       for  desktop (4 columns)
col-xs-6        for   tablets  (2 columns)
col-???-12  for phone  (1 columns)

Or please clarify if I am missing the obvious

Comment: This isn't exactly a "flaw". The distinction between tablets and phones is nebulous, as some phones have higher resolution that some tablets, and the pixel density ratios complicate further. Unless you're coding for a very specific device list, it's often better to let industry standard rule the day.

Comment: That said, the deleted answer by user3361996 is a better approach. It's also an answer that benefits the community more than your very specific set of CSS statements.

Comment: @isherwood - What was the deleted answer? (I don't have enough rep to see other folks' deleted posts.)

Comment: "If you downloaded the Bootstrap CSS file (not using a CDN) you can just change the min-width on the .col-sm media query from 768px to 480px. Then using class col-sm-6 will be for 480px and up and .col-xs-12 will give you the single column you want below 480px."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add more media queries and extra styles

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px){

.callout-wrap, .vertical_photo {
    margin-top:10px;}   

.banner-left, .banner-right, .content-left-side, .content-right-side{
width:100%;

}

.border_drop_bg {
margin-top:10px;
width:100%;}

.vertical_photo {
display:none;}  


 }
```

Answer (score 10):

According to their [documentation on the Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you should be using the 'xs' classes for phones, 'sm' for tablets, and 'md' classes for desktop.

Comment: Well, it may say that, but if you download it xs is for 768 and below.

Comment: Just ran into this issue.  Seems like a bug on bootstrap.  Seems like col-xs-* is defined outside of the media queries in grid css which according to their documentation, should not be.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite understand why there is a problem.  But according to below guide,

Medium is for iPad Landsacape.
Small is for iPad Portrait.
Extra Small is for phones.

http://mspangenberg.github.io/Bootstrap-3-Grids/devices.html